# MonoGame - monogame tool not build in visual studio

Tags: monogame

i create a new project in visual studio 2017 in monogame windows platform and when i double click on.

in content mgcb i load png file for example and click build and nothing happening i don't get error or see something move.
why this happening?

i try to load 4 files: 
crosshairs
galleryFont
sky
target

visual studio code:

```
  namespace shooter_gallery
  {
   /// <summary>
   /// This is the main type for your game.
   /// </summary>
  public class Game1 : Game
    {
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back ==  ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

thanks

Comment: We will probably need more information than just that. 

The mgcb file won't actually do something but transform the elements in a format for Monogame.

If you want to launch your game, you need to do it from Visual Studio, not the Content Pipeline tool.

Also, the code you added is the default code, which should show you an empty screen when launched. Nothing seems to related to the resources you mentionned.